# Removing multiple array values with Array.filter()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings:

```
let arr = ["1", ":", "3", "0", " ", "P", "M"];
```

I want to remove the `":"` and the whitespace using *one* filter helper. Is this possible? It works if I chain the methods together.

```
arr = arr.filter(n => n !== ":").filter(n => n !== " ");
```

Is there a way that I could run this inside of only one filter method without chaining it? I realize I could also get this done with `map()` and run a conditional for string comparisons, but I was curious if it could be done with `filter()`.

Comment: How about `arr.filter(n => n !== ":" && n !== " ")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chain the conditionals with an AND operator, like this:

```
arr.filter(n => n !== ":" && n !== " ");
```

Comment: Wow, I feel very silly for not thinking to try that. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You approach only needs to join the conditions using AND logical operator

```
arr.filter(n => n !== ":" && n !== " ");
                          ^^
```

This approach uses the function `test` as a handler for the function `filter`

**This is the regex:** **[`[:\s]`](https://regex101.com/r/4QPXIM/1)**

```js
let arr = ["1", ":", "3", "0", " ", "P", "M"],
    result = arr.filter(s => !/[:\s]/.test(s));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

---

### As academy approach you can join replace and split

**Regexp:** **[`/[:\s]/g`](https://regex101.com/r/t3SotN/1)**

*Assuming the other elements don't have **spaces** nor **colons***

```js
let arr = ["1", ":", "3", "0", " ", "P", "M"],
    result = arr.join('').replace(/[:\s]/g, '').split('');
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression

```
arr.filter(n => !n.match(/[:\s]/) );
```

it will match any of the values inside `[` and `]`

Comment: Using the function match is ugly!

Answer (score 1):

I will rather do it by making blacklist array

```js
let arr = ["1", ":", "3", "0", " ", "P", "M"],
    notAllowed = [' ', ':'];
    
console.log(arr.filter(a => !notAllowed.includes(a)));
```

Comment: really, can you please explain a bit?

Comment: Thanks ele, I changed my answer. Thanks for sharing this thing, I never knew this before. This is the second time I learnt something from you :)

Comment: Interesting approach! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = arr.filter(n => n !== ":" && n !== " ");
```

Pretty simple really! :)